# using c#.net can we read a line or symbol from a word file

Tags: c#-2.0

how can we read a line or symbol from any type of file using c#.net, we can read all the things which is available in the keyboard but we can not read other symbols is it possible to read other symbols using C#.net please anybudy can help me on this

Comment: It is hard for me to figure out your actual question. Do you want to read text from a text file?

Comment: Do you mean MS Word? Which version ? .doc or .docx?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace IOTest
{
    public class program
    {
         public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
              using (Stream s = File.OpenRead(@"C:\AFile.file"))
              {
                   using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
                   {
                        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                   }
              }
         }
    }
}
```

For symbols, you would need to use Regex or something like that...